# Rest Client Add-On for IE?

Tags: internet-explorer, rest

I'm looking to see if anyone knows of a REST client (perhaps an IE addon) that can be used to submit post requests using IE's cookies for authentication and observe the response.

The purpose of this is i am dealing with a web-service that only allows a login from IE and i need to do some debugging with various POST requests. I know i could make it work by creating my own simple rest client that can spoof IE for the purpose of authenticating but that seems like a lot of work just to observe the response of a couple requests.

Comment: If you have Google Chrome, there's [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm?hl=pt-BR&utm_source=chrome-ntp-launcher). You can set the `User-Agent` header from there and fake IE.

Comment: @gustavohenke: that wont work unfortunately. The login process is too complicated and javascript intensive to login via postman, and even with a useragent spoofer for chrome it still doesnt pass javascript validation and allow login.

Comment: So what you need is unit tests!

Comment: @gustavohenke: i fail to see how that would help / be relevant?

Comment: You're required to test the login validations, right? If so, doing unit tests is the best thing. No REST client could do that for you.

Comment: @gustavohenke, unit tests do not replace having a handy rest client.  The question isn't how can I skirt this question...  Unfortunately, I don't have an answer either.  I got here looking for the same thing.  Postman doesn't work b/c my Chrome and FF browsers updated their security and the REST server sucks (for now).  I don't know if OP has similar issue.

Comment: @rfportilla: It was two years ago, so different issue. I was dealing with a web service that only supported IE.